# Convert Double value to Array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have vb.net application which fetches data from the excel and perform some operation.
I am using excel object Range to get the values from excel.
Below is the line of code I am using,

```
    xlsRangetrans = xlsWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_1).Range("Range1")
    Dim transArray(,) As Object = xlsRangetrans.Value
```

The above code runs successfully if I have more than one values in the Range1.
But if I have only one value I am getting error.

Eg: xlsRangetras.value has "123.0,124.0,nothing,nothing" as System.Array which runs successfully

But if xlsRangetras.value has "123.0" as Double, it gives me error.

How to convert Double value to Array in my case.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim helper As Object = xlsRangetrans.Value
    Dim transArray(,) As Object = _
        If(TypeOf helper Is Object(,), helper, {{DirectCast(helper, Object)}})
```

**Update**

Obviously the `If` operator didn't exist in older .NET versions. In this case that piece of code might help.

```
    Dim helper As Object = xlsRangetrans.Value
    Dim transArray(,) As Object
    If TypeOf helper Is Object(,) Then
        transArray = helper
    Else
        transArray = {{DirectCast(helper, Object)}}
    End If
```

Comment: Is it correct syntax. Because I am getting error in {{DirectCast(helper,Object)}}. "Expression Expected"

Comment: I think the problem is not the {{}} construct but the If operator. Would you try if it works with my update above.

Comment: Instead of DirectCast I tried with casting like 'New Object(,) {{xlsRangetrans.Value, Nothing}}'. It works... Thanks

Comment: Interesting... which Visual Studio and .NET versions are you using?